# How to upload Images to Facebook Album with order using Facebook C# SDK Batch Processing

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

From a desktop application I am uploading Images to **Facebook** Album using [Facebook c# sdk](http://facebooksdk.net).
I have to upload large number of images (100 - 500). So I've tried with the c# sdk's Batch method as follows:

```
        dynamic result = fb.Batch(
            new FacebookBatchParameter(Facebook.HttpMethod.Post, "/albumId/photos", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "message", "picture 1 msg" }, { "pic1", new FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = "image/jpeg", FileName = "Tulips.jpg" }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg")) } }),
            new FacebookBatchParameter(Facebook.HttpMethod.Post, "/albumId/photos", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "message", "picture 2 msg" }, { "pic2", new FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = "image/jpeg", FileName = "Penguins.jpg" }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg")) } }));
```

I followed the steps from [here](http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-multiple-file-uploads-in-batch-requests). But I also need to keep the images' orders but with batch processing Images' orders are not maintained, single post method for each image will slow down the process.

I have requested batch processing for each 10 images, give a delay then again 10 images and so on.

Is there any way to upload images to Facebook using Batch Processing retaining order using Facebook C# sdk or any other way to upload large number of images faster keeping the Images' order ?